# How do I use Google's Warm Strategy Cache from workbox-recipes?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

I am looking for the minimum viable example of how to use the code demonstrated here:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/modules/workbox-recipes/#warm-strategy-cache

I am new to using Workbox (and service workers in general) and am confused about what the 'workbox-recipes' library is predicated on. Am I supposed to have created the service worker before invoking `warmStrategyCache({urls, strategy});`? I thought that this method call creates a service worker for me?

I am ultimately trying to 'warmly' cache (at runtime, not build time, because I am using Contentful) a collection of small videos to be made available so that they play immediately when certain javascript events are triggered.

These videos are hosted on Contentful so it would be a Cross Origin request, in case that matters to this question.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to implement a caching strategy with Workbox, in your service worker code you can either:

1. use directly the functions from these packages: workbox-routing, workbox-strategies, workbox-expiration, workbox plugin workbox-cacheable-response
2. use the caching strategies implemented in workbox-recipes

Either way, you write this code in you service worker script. A SW then has to be built (with workbox-build or any bundler, like esbuild) and then registered on the page with `navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')`.

By the way, just because you are using a CMS like Contentful doesn't mean you can't precache any resource (e.g. the videos you are talking about). You could for example make an API requesto to Contentful at build time and store the videos as blobs using `precacheAndRoute()` from workbox-precaching. But probably precaching large assets (such as videos) is not a good idea.